# Getting an error running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

I'm fairly new to programming and could use some help. I've been running rails s $ -p $PORT -b $IP and it was working just fine but now I'm running into an error. Can anyone help? This is what I get after running rails s -p $PORT -b $IP:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 6 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:252:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:60:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in `block in raw_configuration'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in `raw_configuration'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:64:in `global_configuration'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in `configuration'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:42:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:36:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro.rb:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:123:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in `instance'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:90:in `inherited'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:SimplecodecastsSaas>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.3/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: why don't you just run `rails server`?

Comment: Could you paste your config/application.yml file?

Comment: @Mhmd So what could I do?

Comment: # Add configuration values here, as shown below.
#
# pusher_app_id: "2954"
# pusher_key: 7381a978f7dd7f9a1117
# pusher_secret: abdc3b896a0ffb85d373
stripe_api_key: sk_test_j4pitqOhsguy2ycyS29yasdf
stripe_publishable_key:  pk_test_opJrdVYavI0jqtE9pjKLasdf
#
# production:
  stripe_api_key: sk_test_j4pitqOhsguy2ycyS29yasdf
  stripe_publishable_key: pk_test_opJrdVYavI0jqtE9pjKLasdf  @BroiSatse

Comment: My YAML had a line that was tabbed in. I corrected it. Thanks for the help guys. It's really appreciated.